# Размытие фона объектом в стиле iOS

Tags: css, svg, blur

Привет, мир! Мне нужно размытие фона в стиле iOS чтобы фон размывал определенный блок **как показано на примере**:

[image: Размытие блоком]

На этой картинке видно что блок размывает фоновую картинку. Думаю суть ясна. Возможно это вообще сделать?

Comment: Возможно, но так просто пояснить будет сложно. Могу только подсказать что гуглить. "svg blur mask"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604396/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0/605188#

Comment: вам это вообще где нужно, в html - верстке, или в svg - изображении?

Comment: @Crantisz   не важно